# Function returns nothing in PHP

Tags: php, function, return-value

This Function intends to explorer directory and subdirectories and searches for the files. If a certain part of the file name matches with given $unique_code then it should return that file name. 
But my function returns nothing here.

```
function get_all_directory_and_files($dir, $unique_code, $fileName){

     $dh = new DirectoryIterator($dir);   
     foreach ($dh as $item) {
         if (!$item->isDot()) {
            if ($item->isDir()) {
                get_all_directory_and_files("$dir/$item", $unique_code, $fileName);
            } 
            if ($item->isFile()) {
                $without_extension = pathinfo($item, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $arrData = array();
                $arrData = explode("_",$without_extension);
                if($arrData[4] == $unique_code){
                    $fileName = $item->getFilename();
                }
            }
         }
      }
      return $fileName;
   }

get_all_directory_and_files('uploadFiles', $unique_code, "");
```

Comment: It returns nothing because it doesn't find that file name and you only set `$fileName` if you find something. You should have it either return `false` or a blank string (depending on your business logic) if nothing is found.

Comment: I tested it with "echo". it displays file name when the string matches but returns nothing.

Comment: This is a recursive function which is generally done in two ways, either using a straight return or by using byref parameters, and you have the start of both but they aren't correct. If you really want byref parameters, then `$fileName` should be declared with a lead `&` and `return` chould be used to indicate success/error. If you want regular return, you need to handle your inner call to `get_all_directory_and_files()` and look at what it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my comment above, you aren't using the recursive function to its fullest. You should either be using a byref parameter denoted by `&` or you should be returning when you recurse.

Here's a recursive sample that just returns when something is found and doesn't need that third parameter. (NOTE: There's depth-first and breadth-first searches which if you have a lot of files and/or dirs might matter and you should look into.)

```php
function get_all_directory_and_files(string $dir, string $unique_code): ?string
{
    $dh = new DirectoryIterator($dir);
    foreach ($dh as $item) {
        // Move on if this is just a dot file/folder
        if ($item->isDot()) {
            continue;
        }

        if ($item->isDir()) {
            // Capture the return and check it
            $fileName = get_all_directory_and_files($item->getPathname(), $unique_code);
            if ($fileName) {
                return $fileName;
            }
        }

        if ($item->isFile()) {
            $without_extension = pathinfo($item, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $arrData = explode("_", $without_extension);
            if (count($arrData) >= 5 && $arrData[4] === $unique_code) {
                // Return if found
                return $item->getFilename();
            }
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```

Here's a much shorter version that uses some native PHP extensions to do the same thing. The RegEx could be cleaned up but it should make your pattern pretty obvious.

```php
function get_all_directory_and_files(string $dir, string $unique_code): ?string
{
    $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $fi = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    $unique_code = preg_quote($unique_code, '/');
    $ri = new RegexIterator($fi, "/^[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_${unique_code}(\.|_).*?$/", RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

    $ri->rewind();
    return $ri->current()[0] ?? null;
}
```

A less repetitive version of the RegEx would be:

```php
    $ri = new RegexIterator($fi, "/^([^_]+_){4}${unique_code}(\.|_).*?$/", RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
```